# Using ElementArrayFinder.filter() with async/await

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

I've been using the following function to filter element arrays for the past few years with Webdriver's Control Flow enabled:

```
filterElementsByText (elemList, comparator, locator) {
  return elemList.filter((elem) => {
    let searchTarget = locator ? elem.element(locator) : elem
    return searchTarget.getText().then((text) => text === comparator)
  })
}
```

I am now trying to migrate my repo to using async/await which requires turning off the Control Flow.

This transition has been mostly successful, but I'm having trouble with the function above.  Intermittently, I am seeing this error:

> Failed: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

I am able to reproduce this issue with a test case I've written against https://angularjs.org, although it happens with much higher frequency against my own app.

```
let todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'))
let todoText = element(by.model('todoList.todoText'))
let todoSubmit = element(by.css('[value="add"]'))

let addItem = async (itemLabel = 'write first protractor test') => {
  await todoText.sendKeys(itemLabel)
  return todoSubmit.click()
}

let filterElementsByText = (elemList, comparator, locator) => {
  return elemList.filter((elem) => {
    let searchTarget = locator ? elem.element(locator) : elem
    return searchTarget.getText().then((text) => {
      console.log(`Element text is: ${text}`)
      return text === comparator
    })
  })
}

describe('filter should', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
    await browser.get('https://angularjs.org')

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      await addItem(`item${i}`)
    }
    return addItem()
  })

  it('work', async () => {
    let filteredElements = await filterElementsByText(todoList, 'write first protractor test')
    return expect(filteredElements.length).toEqual(1)
  })
})
```

This is being run with the following set in Protractor's conf file:

```
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false
```

With the simplified test case it seems to occur on 5-10% of executions (although, anecdotally it does seem to occur more frequently once it occurs the first time)

My problem is, this feels like a bug in Webdriver, but I'm not sure what conditions would cause that error so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It sometimes feels like I can produce the issue more frequently if I bump the number of items created in the test up (I use 250 often), but that is also just anecdotal

Comment: If it doesn't occur when the control flow is on, then it's probably because somewhere, the code is trying to resolve multiple Promises at the same time when it should instead wait for the previous one to be resolved. Try to write `filterElementsByText` with some `await` in a loop and without any `map` or `filter` to see if it's the case.

Comment: Writing my own filter function without using ElementArrayFinder.filter() does seem to work and is a good workaround, but I'm trying to understand the nature of this error.  I can see how the multiple Promise situation you describe would, in fact, occur here.. but how does that lead to "Connection refused" ?

Comment: A Selenium command opens a connection with the driver, sends an http request and then close the connection. So I guess that executing multiple commands at the same time is overflowing the driver with connection attempts, which at some point is replying with a `Connection refused`.

Comment: After more playing around, I am still unable to reproduce the problem with the angularjs.org test case after implementing this work around, but it doesn't actually help with my own app.  So filter() is not to blame, but I'm at a loss as to what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reading and wondering, the problem with my own app was two-fold.

First, as described in the comments to the original question, ElementArrayFinder.filter() causes this error because it runs parallel requests for each element in the array.

Secondly (and not apparent in the original question), rather than passing an ElementArrayFinder as described in this test case, I was actually passing in a chained child of each element in the array such as:

```
element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos').$$('span')
```

Looking at the Webdriver output as this happens I noticed that this then causes all those locators to be retrieved in parallel leading to the same error.

I was able to work around both issues by filtering this way:

```
let filterElementsByText = async (elemList, comparator, locator) => {
  let filteredElements = []
  let elems = await elemList
  for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    let elem = await elems[i]
    let searchTarget = locator ? elem.element(locator) : elem
    let text = await searchTarget.getText()
    if (text === comparator) {
      filteredElements.push(elem)
    }
  }
  return filteredElements
}
```

This unblocks me, but it still feels like an issue that these functions are just unusable with async/await.